# How to sort bash functions alphabetically?

Tags: functions, bash, sorting

My boss is a bit of a neat freak. He wants the functions in my functions.sh be ordered alphabetically.

```
foo() {
  echo foo
}

baa() {
  echo baa
}
```

So baa should appear first in the file.

Can emacs help me do this? I have tons of methods in this file.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have things like you show, and no blank lines, then `sort-paragraphs` will do what you want. Go to the start of the file, and invoke it.

Assuming that your real life example is harder than this, I think you will need to write a little bit of lisp to provide some functions to use with `sort-subr`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @icarus' answer, you could potentially use `sort-pages` with a custom `page-delimiter`.

If it's true that a line starting with `}` is always the end of a function, then:

- <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq-local page-delimiter "^}")` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Mark the region
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sort-pages` <kbd>RET</kbd>

---

A classic hack is to substitute some non-conflicting token for newlines such that every record becomes a single line, then sort the lines, and finally turn the tokens back into newlines.

You could also use common shell commands for this approach.  Your delimiter might be multiple characters, but the NUL character is a good delimiter, if your tools support using it.  The following won't be portable across all systems, but may work for you.

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-|</kbd> `sed -z -e 's/\n}\n\n*/&\x0/g' | sort -z | tr -d '\000'` <kbd>RET</kbd>

As before, this assumes that records end with `}` on a line by itself.